# Using bcrypt on client side web page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bcrypt, bcryptjs

For crypto-js, it was easy to use it like:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

Is there any similar option for bcrypt, so that I can add it to a static page?

Comment: First result of googling "cdn bcryptjs" gives you [this](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bcryptjs/2.2.0). Have you even tried to find it on your own?

Comment: actually I was lacking the right key words, I was using sort of elaborated words for searching, in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it on [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/bcrypt). I'd have to note that [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) (last update was 6 years ago - quite old) is a modified version of [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) (last update was 8 months ago - it's the official version anyway). if you want to use bcryptjs, find it on [jsDeliver](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/bcryptjs) too (yet not recommended).